# Getting an email attachment into a C# structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, arrays, office365

I am very curious about this.  I am a new hire, and am working on a app that will call the MS 365 api, and crawl the desired mail mailbox.  My objective is to filter out any emails with attachments, retrieve the sender name, sender subject, and finally the attachment.  This is a console app that will run on a server, so from what i understand, in order to achieve best performance a C# structure is the way to go.  This is where I am stuck.  I built my structure, with the appropriate properties which I need.  Oddly enough I am setting a Byte array property (I never done this).  Then in my function I am calling the api, then making a list of my struct in in order to add each email as an object  I feel this will improve performance.  Now I am able to retrieve the sender of the email, and subject with no issue because they are strings.  But now, How can I get the attachment in order to make this a complete email object in memory.  This is a snippet of my code.

The Struct:

```
struct Emailed_Expenses
{
    private string sender;
    private string subject;
    private byte [] attachment;        

    public string Email_Sender
    {
        get
        {
            return sender;
        }
        set
        {
            sender = value;
        }
    }
    public string Email_Subject
    {
        get
        {
            return subject;
        }
        set
        {
            subject = value;
        }
    } 
    public byte[] Email_Attachment
    {
        get
        {
            return attachment;
        }
        set
        {
            attachment = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The email crawler

```
        public static List<Emailed_Expenses> Get_Star_Mailbox()
    {
        //var star_user = "*******@dell.com";
        OutlookServicesClient star_Mail_Box = Start_OutLook_Services();
        List<Emailed_Expenses> star_Inbox = new List<Emailed_Expenses>();

        try
        {

            var Email_Box = star_Mail_Box.Users["******@dell.com"].Messages.ExecuteAsync().Result;

            var messages = Email_Box.CurrentPage;
            //var messages = star_Mail_Box.Me.Folders["Inbox"].Messages.OrderByDescending(m => m.DateTimeReceived).Take(10).ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                if (message.Attachments.CurrentPage.Count > 0)
                {
                    Emailed_Expenses email = new Emailed_Expenses
                    {
                        Email_Sender = message.Sender.ToString(),
                        Email_Subject = message.Subject.ToString(),
                        >>>>>>>>Email_Attachment = byte [message.Attachments],<<<<< this is what I am talking about !!!!*****
                    };

                    star_Inbox.Add(email);
                }

            }
        }
```

I now this may seem a bit naive but I been working on this for about 11 hours now, and I have not found any examples on line that can guide me to bring in an attachment to my structure.

Main Objective :  I would like to read an email attachment into my structure.

Comment: I can tell you for sure that your structure is wrong, I never work with this API, but one mail can have multiple attachments. So you should have in your class List<Attachments> property. Also you need to have separate class Attachments in which you have properties ID(at least I remember they had IDs), Name and Content which will be byte[]. In your code message.Attachments should contain all return attachments. This is what I think.

Comment: You are right when you pointed out that multiple attachment, I was very blind to that thanks.  Could you explain a bit on the attachment class, please.  Sorry if I am bothering but this is new to me too, but two heads are better than one

Comment: You should loop all message.Attachments. In the message.Attachments[0] you should have properties Name,ID(probably) or something like content. Your Attachment class should have structure ID->string(possible guid too, like I said I don't know the API), Name->string, Content->byte[]. Loop the attachments save the data in your attachment class after that add the attachment to your List<Attachments> in your mail class.

Comment: Ok, I am doing that currently in my for each loop, I am greeting every message in messages with an attachment.  I am getting sender and subject with out a problem.  Getting the attachment is what I am stuck on.  Do you suggest I pursue a class approach?  I was told a structure would make this app more efficient?  Where I am stuck at is getting the attachment.

Comment: Before going any further in C# (hence .NET) development, you must absolutely understanding the in-and-outs of stacking/heaping struct vs class in C#.  As far as I am concerned setting a struct here will not bring any noticeable performance benefits. This reference is quite old but still good in my humble opinion  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are 2 types of attachments that can be on a Message: ItemAttachments and FileAttachments. ItemAttachments are other Outlook objects (messages, events, etc) that are attached. For these you get an object of the type of attachment, so you won't have the binary data to work with. So I'm assuming you only care about FileAttachments.

As mybirthname said in a comment, you need to loop through each of the attachments. If it's a FileAttachment, then you can use the ContentBytes property to get the byte array of the attachment. Here's what I think it would look like, assuming you change Email_Attachment to a `List<>` that can hold all of the attachments:

```
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    Emailed_Expenses email = null;

    foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments.CurrentPage)
    {
        FileAttachment file = attachment as FileAttachment;
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (email == null)
            {
                email = new Emailed_Expenses
                {
                    Email_Sender = message.Sender.ToString(),
                    Email_Subject = message.Subject,
                    Email_Attachment = new List<byte[]>
                };
            }

            email.Email_Attachment.Add(file.ContentBytes);
        }
    }

    if (file != null)
    {
        star_Inbox.Add(email);
    }
}
```

This is off the top of my head and untested, so it might have some bugs, but I think it should give you the general idea. Also note that I removed the call to `.ToString()` on `message.Subject`, since `Subject` is already a string. I'm also not sure what calling `.ToString()` on the `message.Sender` will look like exactly. If you already know that gives you what you want, then great! But you might need to go down to the `message.Sender.EmailAddress.Name` or `message.Sender.EmailAddress.Address` as appropriate.

As far as whether this would be better as a struct or a class, that really depends on how it's going to be used throughout the rest of the application. This seems like each instance is going to be fairly large, which you usually don't want for structs. However, that's a guideline, not a hard-and-fast rule. How it's used is a much better determinant for whether it should be a class or struct.